# Capistrano 3.6.1 not deploying latest revision if using a branch

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

Capistrano 3.6.1 is not deploying latest revision if using a branch. I deploy `dev` branch, on Githab `dev` branch is set as default.

`config/deploy/staging.rb`

```
set :branch, 'dev'
```

I commit to `dev` branch locally, push it to `dev` on remote and I can see the commits on the remote `dev` branch on Gitlab but Capistrano is not pulling them. It sets a mirror clone of the old revision upon every deploy. I compared `dev` branch against `master` and `master` is totally different, it doesn't contain the revision that I see as set as `current` after a deploy.

GIT
Local machine

```
git --version
git version 2.22.0
```

Server

```
git --version
git version 2.1.4
```

Capistrano 3.6.1

I found similar issue https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/1773
It was never fixed, only a workaround was proposed - delete the `repo` folder, which did not work for me. Stackoverflow answers in other threads suggest deleting `repo` folder as well, but it didn't work for me so I haven't found any solution for this so far.

Full stacktrace:
https://gist.github.com/jedrekdomanski/de540411a7fe02257fd4f225ab6f7165

```
cap staging deploy --trace        
** Invoke staging (first_time)
** Execute staging
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
** Invoke deploy (first_time)
** Execute deploy
** Invoke deploy:starting (first_time)
** Execute deploy:starting
** Invoke deploy:check (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check
** Invoke git:check (first_time)
** Invoke git:wrapper (first_time)
** Execute git:wrapper
  INFO [94b69fa0] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp as apps@195.128.228.103
 DEBUG [94b69fa0] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp
  INFO [94b69fa0] Finished in 0.224 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG Uploading /tmp/git-ssh-lauber-frontend-staging-jedrek.sh 0.0%
  INFO Uploading /tmp/git-ssh-lauber-frontend-staging-jedrek.sh 100.0%
  INFO [07964889] Running /usr/bin/env chmod 700 /tmp/git-ssh-lauber-frontend-staging-jedrek.sh as apps@195.128.228.103
 DEBUG [07964889] Command: /usr/bin/env chmod 700 /tmp/git-ssh-lauber-frontend-staging-jedrek.sh
  INFO [07964889] Finished in 0.029 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Execute git:check
  INFO [564c96e3] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@gitlab.ideamotiv.com:lauber/lauber-frontend.git as apps@195.128.228.103
 DEBUG [564c96e3] Command: ( export GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/echo" GIT_SSH="/tmp/git-ssh-lauber-frontend-staging-jedrek.sh" ; /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@gitlab.ideamotiv.com:lauber/lauber-frontend.git )
 DEBUG [564c96e3]   c30af359a8e0fa0494d842005d29cee8ab685ba6    refs/heads/LK-743-Headers-optimizations
b8b65e312245e409c11d40d5fc791f501f137505    refs/heads/LK-744-Add-meta-tags-and-meta-descriptions
a78d7aa366d944d24bccbe26a3563fbab0fbde53    refs/heads/LK-746-Friendly-urls
3cf9da5b998b22e45fb0bb409aeea3d91f4e4e42    refs/heads/LK-748-Images-alt-descriptions
23953e6d2a0bb7f8e71f73a9cbab0f92d2a32ba3    refs/heads/LK-750-Rich-snippets
be8ae00a1ae6da190effa3144d314039ed728077    refs/heads/LK-757-Add-subdomains-for-languages
3503c45fbf2475a7ae5cdb34227fd4e187fff031    refs/heads/LK-761-List-page-for-categories
17549a551c28f1fdd9b6688633af2b0ae327e3b9    refs/heads/LK-763-Title-and-short-description-for-part-page
67357f094433021d13577b4d84c038998064cb63    refs/heads/catalog
d4171ad2b8d8cbdde3dc858a7bb1f0eb2233ee93    refs/heads/dev
39f90d30754c32bd422c00df8139a8a369398864    refs/heads/master
8e12f9b452e7ba41c432554c68302a035e62a97a    refs/heads/properties
8ce29ee1dfe13828188e5d5b0275e211dc9f4032    refs/heads/shop
5becebcddb8d39ffcdc84a3b33af2c3a47e23db1    refs/heads/test-deploy-branch
ae3ea93e749c99d4d2e17986b6afe35b23c5b5b3    refs/heads/vehicles
INFO [564c96e3] Finished in 1.090 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Invoke deploy:check:directories (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check:directories
  INFO [74bfa000] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/shared /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/releases as apps@195.128.228.103
 DEBUG [74bfa000] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/shared /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/releases
  INFO [74bfa000] Finished in 0.033 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Invoke deploy:check:linked_dirs (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check:linked_dirs
  INFO [0e7b5cbb] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/shared/app/translations as apps@195.128.228.103
 DEBUG [0e7b5cbb] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/shared/app/translations
  INFO [0e7b5cbb] Finished in 0.031 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Invoke deploy:check:make_linked_dirs (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check:make_linked_dirs
  INFO [42e2f0c1] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/shared as apps@195.128.228.103
 DEBUG [42e2f0c1] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/shared
  INFO [42e2f0c1] Finished in 0.030 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Invoke deploy:check:linked_files (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check:linked_files
 DEBUG [1385d44d] Running [ -f /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/shared/.env ] as apps@195.128.228.103
 DEBUG [1385d44d] Command: [ -f /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/shared/.env ]
 DEBUG [1385d44d] Finished in 0.031 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Invoke deploy:set_previous_revision (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_previous_revision
 DEBUG [e5f3d36e] Running [ -f /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/current/REVISION ] as apps@195.128.228.103
 DEBUG [e5f3d36e] Command: [ -f /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/current/REVISION ]
 DEBUG [e5f3d36e] Finished in 0.032 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [e5ce6be7] Running /usr/bin/env cat /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/current/REVISION 2>/dev/null as apps@195.128.228.103
 DEBUG [e5ce6be7] Command: /usr/bin/env cat /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/current/REVISION 2>/dev/null
 DEBUG [e5ce6be7]   d4171ad2b8d8cbdde3dc858a7bb1f0eb2233ee93
 DEBUG [e5ce6be7] Finished in 0.026 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 ** Invoke deploy:started (first_time)
** Execute deploy:started
** Invoke deploy:updating (first_time)
** Invoke deploy:new_release_path (first_time)
** Execute deploy:new_release_path
** Execute deploy:updating
** Invoke git:create_release (first_time)
** Invoke git:update (first_time)
** Invoke git:clone (first_time)
** Invoke git:wrapper 
** Execute git:clone
 DEBUG [bbadb24c] Running [ -f /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/repo/HEAD ] as apps@195.128.228.103
 DEBUG [bbadb24c] Command: [ -f /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/repo/HEAD ]
 DEBUG [bbadb24c] Finished in 0.025 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO The repository mirror is at /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/repo
** Execute git:update
 DEBUG [b156b58d] Running if test ! -d /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi as apps@195.128.228.103
 DEBUG [b156b58d] Command: if test ! -d /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi
 DEBUG [b156b58d] Finished in 0.029 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [2fa00ea8] Running /usr/bin/env git remote update --prune as apps@195.128.228.103
 DEBUG [2fa00ea8] Command: cd /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/repo && ( export GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/echo" GIT_SSH="/tmp/git-ssh-lauber-frontend-staging-jedrek.sh" ; /usr/bin/env git remote update --prune )
 DEBUG [2fa00ea8]   Fetching origin
  INFO [2fa00ea8] Finished in 0.887 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Execute git:create_release
 DEBUG [8ed09795] Running if test ! -d /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi as apps@195.128.228.103
 DEBUG [8ed09795] Command: if test ! -d /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi
 DEBUG [8ed09795] Finished in 0.024 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [d7be5387] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/releases/20190712200021 as apps@195.128.228.103
 DEBUG [d7be5387] Command: cd /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/repo && ( export GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/echo" GIT_SSH="/tmp/git-ssh-lauber-frontend-staging-jedrek.sh" ; /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/releases/20190712200021 )
  INFO [d7be5387] Finished in 0.034 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [b4c34014] Running /usr/bin/env git archive dev | tar -x -f - -C /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/releases/20190712200021 as apps@195.128.228.103
 DEBUG [b4c34014] Command: cd /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/repo && ( export GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/echo" GIT_SSH="/tmp/git-ssh-lauber-frontend-staging-jedrek.sh" ; /usr/bin/env git archive dev | tar -x -f - -C /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/releases/20190712200021 )
  INFO [b4c34014] Finished in 0.079 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Invoke deploy:set_current_revision (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_current_revision
** Invoke git:set_current_revision (first_time)
** Execute git:set_current_revision
 DEBUG [b10c1d3f] Running if test ! -d /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi as apps@195.128.228.103
 DEBUG [b10c1d3f] Command: if test ! -d /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi
 DEBUG [b10c1d3f] Finished in 0.029 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [e21a9758] Running /usr/bin/env git rev-list --max-count=1 dev as apps@195.128.228.103
 DEBUG [e21a9758] Command: cd /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/repo && ( export GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/echo" GIT_SSH="/tmp/git-ssh-lauber-frontend-staging-jedrek.sh" ; /usr/bin/env git rev-list --max-count=1 dev )
 DEBUG [e21a9758]   d4171ad2b8d8cbdde3dc858a7bb1f0eb2233ee93
 DEBUG [e21a9758] Finished in 0.032 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [159ee256] Running if test ! -d /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/releases/20190712200021; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/releases/20190712200021'" 1>&2; false; fi as apps@195.128.228.103
 DEBUG [159ee256] Command: if test ! -d /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/releases/20190712200021; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/releases/20190712200021'" 1>&2; false; fi
 DEBUG [159ee256] Finished in 0.030 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [189a4cd6] Running /usr/bin/env echo "d4171ad2b8d8cbdde3dc858a7bb1f0eb2233ee93" >> REVISION as apps@195.128.228.103
 DEBUG [189a4cd6] Command: cd /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/releases/20190712200021 && /usr/bin/env echo "d4171ad2b8d8cbdde3dc858a7bb1f0eb2233ee93" >> REVISION
  INFO [189a4cd6] Finished in 0.026 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Invoke deploy:symlink:shared (first_time)
** Execute deploy:symlink:shared
** Invoke deploy:symlink:linked_files (first_time)
** Execute deploy:symlink:linked_files
  INFO [2913d95e] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/releases/20190712200021 as apps@195.128.228.103
 DEBUG [2913d95e] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/releases/20190712200021
  INFO [2913d95e] Finished in 0.029 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [f906c2bd] Running [ -L /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/releases/20190712200021/.env ] as apps@195.128.228.103
 DEBUG [f906c2bd] Command: [ -L /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/releases/20190712200021/.env ]
 DEBUG [f906c2bd] Finished in 0.038 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [b18fce9c] Running [ -f /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/releases/20190712200021/.env ] as apps@195.128.228.103
 DEBUG [b18fce9c] Command: [ -f /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/releases/20190712200021/.env ]
 DEBUG [b18fce9c] Finished in 0.031 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
  INFO [c7602359] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/shared/.env /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/releases/20190712200021/.env as apps@195.128.228.103
DEBUG [c7602359] Command: /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/shared/.env /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/releases/20190712200021/.env
  INFO [c7602359] Finished in 0.026 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Invoke deploy:symlink:linked_dirs (first_time)
** Execute deploy:symlink:linked_dirs
  INFO [4bbf4fc8] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/releases/20190712200021/app as apps@195.128.228.103
 DEBUG [4bbf4fc8] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/releases/20190712200021/app
  INFO [4bbf4fc8] Finished in 0.026 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [d8b883a0] Running [ -L /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/releases/20190712200021/app/translations ] as apps@195.128.228.103
 DEBUG [d8b883a0] Command: [ -L /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/releases/20190712200021/app/translations ]
 DEBUG [d8b883a0] Finished in 0.030 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [b7dfd293] Running [ -d /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/releases/20190712200021/app/translations ] as apps@195.128.228.103
 DEBUG [b7dfd293] Command: [ -d /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/releases/20190712200021/app/translations ]
 DEBUG [b7dfd293] Finished in 0.032 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [9960c6d6] Running /usr/bin/env rm -rf /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/releases/20190712200021/app/translations as apps@195.128.228.103
 DEBUG [9960c6d6] Command: /usr/bin/env rm -rf /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/releases/20190712200021/app/translations
  INFO [9960c6d6] Finished in 0.032 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [e75dc524] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/shared/app/translations /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/releases/20190712200021/app/translations as apps@195.128.228.103
 DEBUG [e75dc524] Command: /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/shared/app/translations /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/releases/20190712200021/app/translations
  INFO [e75dc524] Finished in 0.032 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Invoke deploy:updated (first_time)
** Execute deploy:updated
** Invoke deploy:publishing (first_time)
** Execute deploy:publishing
** Invoke deploy:symlink:release (first_time)
** Execute deploy:symlink:release
  INFO [56ca3dec] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/releases/20190712200021 /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/releases/current as apps@195.128.228.103
 DEBUG [56ca3dec] Command: /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/releases/20190712200021 /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/releases/current
  INFO [56ca3dec] Finished in 0.031 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [f5ae2076] Running /usr/bin/env mv /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/releases/current /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production as apps@195.128.228.103
 DEBUG [f5ae2076] Command: /usr/bin/env mv /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/releases/current /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production
  INFO [f5ae2076] Finished in 0.033 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Invoke deploy:published (first_time)
** Execute deploy:published
** Invoke deploy:finishing (first_time)
** Execute deploy:finishing
** Invoke deploy:cleanup (first_time)
** Invoke npm:build (first_time)
** Execute npm:build
  INFO [afd2116b] Running cd /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/current && npm install && npm run build as apps@195.128.228.103
 DEBUG [afd2116b] Command: cd /home/apps/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/current && npm install && npm run build
 DEBUG [afd2116b]
```

`dev` branch on the server

```
apps@hoth:~/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production/current$ cat REVISION
d4171ad2b8d8cbdde3dc858a7bb1f0eb2233ee93
```

Local `dev` branch

```
commit 18335e66a1d8a2d18649b320f7220e67f93f6d3c (HEAD -> dev, origin/dev, origin/HEAD)
Date:   Fri Jul 12 11:53:02 2019 +0200

    Test commit

commit f153ce5c836ff4f5fa088499bfe4b477b4bee10b (Update-part-substitution-header, Update-part-page-title)
Date:   Tue Jul 9 10:43:43 2019 +0200

    Update part page title

commit 39f94d47e8426a33eb8ef53b15d8ab79cebb2343 (Update-parts-image-alt-and-meta-tags)
Date:   Tue Jul 9 10:07:26 2019 +0200

    Update parts image alt and meta tags

commit d4171ad2b8d8cbdde3dc858a7bb1f0eb2233ee93
Merge: da5c334 3503c45

    See merge request lauber/lauber-frontend!24
```

So the last 3 commits are not available in git repo on the server but are available both on local and remote repo (Gitlab)

```
apps@hoth:~/app/shop-lauber-frontend/production$ cat revisions.log
Branch dev (at d4171ad2b8d8cbdde3dc858a7bb1f0eb2233ee93) deployed as release 20190515113248 by sylwiaszymanska
Branch dev (at d4171ad2b8d8cbdde3dc858a7bb1f0eb2233ee93) deployed as release 20190710102344 by jedrek
Branch dev (at d4171ad2b8d8cbdde3dc858a7bb1f0eb2233ee93) deployed as release 20190710104326 by jedrek
Branch dev (at d4171ad2b8d8cbdde3dc858a7bb1f0eb2233ee93) deployed as release 20190710110701 by jedrek
Branch dev (at d4171ad2b8d8cbdde3dc858a7bb1f0eb2233ee93) deployed as release 20190710135109 by jedrek
Branch dev (at d4171ad2b8d8cbdde3dc858a7bb1f0eb2233ee93) deployed as release 20190710140939 by jedrek
Branch dev (at d4171ad2b8d8cbdde3dc858a7bb1f0eb2233ee93) deployed as release 20190710164118 by jedrek
Branch dev (at d4171ad2b8d8cbdde3dc858a7bb1f0eb2233ee93) deployed as release 20190710171703 by jedrek
Branch dev (at d4171ad2b8d8cbdde3dc858a7bb1f0eb2233ee93) deployed as release 20190712094210 by jedrek
Branch dev (at d4171ad2b8d8cbdde3dc858a7bb1f0eb2233ee93) deployed as release 20190712095436 by jedrek
Branch dev (at d4171ad2b8d8cbdde3dc858a7bb1f0eb2233ee93) deployed as release 20190712145228 by jedrek
Branch dev (at d4171ad2b8d8cbdde3dc858a7bb1f0eb2233ee93) deployed as release 20190712160325 by jedrek
```

It deployed the old revision.
Line 69 is checking the previous revision.
Line 91 is updating `git remote update --prune` without previously pulling latest commits from repo?
Line 113 is setting the old revision as current.

On the previous try, before fetching origin it did `git clone --mirror git@XXXX/lauber-frontend.git repo` but this time I don't see it anymore. I am not sure why it is doing a mirror clone but it's not pulling latest changes anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I got help from Capistrano dev team which pointed me to the different repo urls in my capistrano config. I totally missed it. It looked like the repo url might have changed after I took the project over and I was unaware of it. I updated the repo_url and had to also remove the `repo` folder on the server and that solved my problem.